# Add and Fetch content with html tags - MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, fetch

I am trying to store a following content into a mysql table with name `htmlcontent`.

It has three columns `id` (int), `content` (longtext) and `content_head` (VARCHAR)

The content column will have html content as below.

```
<p><span class="icon note big"></span>Content Goes here</p>
<p><span class="icon note big"></span>Content Goes here</p>
<p><span class="icon note big"></span>Content Goes here</p>
<p><span class="icon note big"></span>Content Goes here</p>
```

I tried storing this from phpmyadmin with following query

```
INSERT
INTO htmlcontent
(content, content_head) 
VALUES ('Content head','<p><span class="icon note big"></span>Content Goes here</p><p><span class="icon note big"></span>Content Goes here</p><p><span class="icon note big"></span>Content Goes here</p><p><span class="icon note big"></span>Content Goes here</p>')
```

It got inserted without any issues.

I tried doing a `SELECT` query as follows.

```
SELECT*FROM htmlcontent WHERE id='1'
```

It worked on phpmyadmin but didn't worked when I did it with PHP.

The php code I tried is as below.

```
    if(!empty($id)){

                $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM htmlcontent WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1", $this->db);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
                    $result['is_data'] = 1;

                    $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
                }
                else {

        $message = array('is_data' => 0, "message" => "No Content Found");
                    $this->response($this->json($message), 200);
                }    

        }
```

I am not getting any response to my query with this code. I am not getting the error message in the code too. Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: You outputted `$id` and confirmed it is `1` already? Is error reporting on? Also it is safer to use prepared statements. If `$id` is set from user input you are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Yes I echoed the value. The $id is passing correctly into the condition. I couldn't get any errors. It is working fine when I remove the column with longtext and try the same query.

Comment: $id is not user input. I am using that as an id to the content to be displayed on a web page.

Comment: `when I remove the column with longtext and try the same query` What do you mean by that, `content` isn't in the query you've provided.

Comment: I mentioned 'It has three columns id(int), content(longtext) and content_head (VARCHAR)' . The column content is with longtext as it's datatype. When I remove it(the entire column), the rest of the column could be fetched. The issue is with fetching the html content from the content column.

Comment: Do you mean you delete the data from the record and then it is selectable?

Comment: I mean deleting the entire column where i store the html content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86929/discussion-between-bigb-and-chris85).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was resolved in chat.